# I am a dual citizen of Canada and US looking to marry a Canadian Citizen

Tags: canada, marriage, usa, dual-citizenship

If I marry a Canadian Citizen, will it make any difference at all to my US Citizenship and Residency?  Will it make any difference at all to staying in and leaving Canada?  Will it make any difference at all to staying in and leaving the United States?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot lose US citizenship simply by marrying somebody else (no matter who it is). Your right to US residency is linked to your US citizenship, so you always have a right to enter, live, and work in the US.

Similar for Canada, as a Canadian citizen you always have a right to enter, live, and work in Canada.

Your future spouse will find it easier to live and work in the US because of your US citizenship. There's still some paperwork, but it's simpler.

Comment: She is a elected official in Canada, so will need to stay in Canada for at least 4 more years.  I work in the US and travel abroad for work a significant portion of the year.  If we get married in Canada, I want to make sure none of that changes.

Comment: @LarryGilbert why would any of that change? Tens of thousands of US citizens if not hundreds of thousands have married foreign spouses. You cannot be deprived of your US citizenship without your consent except in very specific circumstances that can occur only for an exceedingly small number of people. These include perpetrating fraud in your naturalization (if you're naturalized) or becoming head of state, head of government, or foreign minister of another country (and even there it's not definite that it would result in loss of US citizenship).